# Android Training Sample- Scheduler Sample- unable to stop alarm

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, alarm

I am using the sample code(Scheduler.zip) available on the Android developer training website- http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/index.html

Here's the code:-

MainActivity.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.scheduler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


/**
 * This sample demonstrates how to schedule an alarm that causes a service to
 * be started. This is useful when you want to schedule alarms that initiate
 * long-running operations, such as retrieving a daily forecast.
 * This particular sample retrieves content from the Google home page once a day and  
 * checks it for the search string "doodle". If it finds this string, that indicates 
 * that the page contains a custom doodle instead of the standard Google logo.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SampleAlarmReceiver alarm = new SampleAlarmReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Menu options to set and cancel the alarm.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // When the user clicks START ALARM, set the alarm.
            case R.id.start_action:
                alarm.setAlarm(this);
                return true;
            // When the user clicks CANCEL ALARM, cancel the alarm. 
            case R.id.cancel_action:

                alarm.cancelAlarm(this);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

SampleAlarmReceiver.java

```
package com.example.android.scheduler;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * When the alarm fires, this WakefulBroadcastReceiver receives the broadcast Intent 
 * and then starts the IntentService {@code SampleSchedulingService} to do some work.
 */
public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    // The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm services.
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    // The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(alarm_onreceive)
        /* 
         * If your receiver intent includes extras that need to be passed along to the
         * service, use setComponent() to indicate that the service should handle the
         * receiver's intent. For example:
         * 
         * ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), 
         *      MyService.class.getName());
         *
         * // This intent passed in this call will include the wake lock extra as well as 
         * // the receiver intent contents.
         * startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
         * 
         * In this example, we simply create a new intent to deliver to the service.
         * This intent holds an extra identifying the wake lock.
         */
        Intent service = new Intent(context, SampleSchedulingService.class);

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, service);
        // END_INCLUDE(alarm_onreceive)
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(set_alarm)
    /**
     * Sets a repeating alarm that runs once a day at approximately 8:30 a.m. When the
     * alarm fires, the app broadcasts an Intent to this WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
     * @param context
     */
    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Set the alarm's trigger time to 8:30 a.m.
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        /* 
         * If you don't have precise time requirements, use an inexact repeating alarm
         * the minimize the drain on the device battery.
         * 
         * The call below specifies the alarm type, the trigger time, the interval at
         * which the alarm is fired, and the alarm's associated PendingIntent.
         * It uses the alarm type RTC_WAKEUP ("Real Time Clock" wake up), which wakes up 
         * the device and triggers the alarm according to the time of the device's clock. 
         * 
         * Alternatively, you can use the alarm type ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP to trigger 
         * an alarm based on how much time has elapsed since the device was booted. This 
         * is the preferred choice if your alarm is based on elapsed time--for example, if 
         * you simply want your alarm to fire every 60 minutes. You only need to use 
         * RTC_WAKEUP if you want your alarm to fire at a particular date/time. Remember 
         * that clock-based time may not translate well to other locales, and that your 
         * app's behavior could be affected by the user changing the device's time setting.
         * 
         * Here are some examples of ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP:
         * 
         * // Wake up the device to fire a one-time alarm in one minute.
         * alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
         *         SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
         *         60*1000, alarmIntent);
         *        
         * // Wake up the device to fire the alarm in 30 minutes, and every 30 minutes
         * // after that.
         * alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
         *         AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, 
         *         AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
         */

        // Set the alarm to fire at approximately 8:30 a.m., according to the device's
        // clock, and to repeat once a day.
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 2*60*1000, alarmIntent);



        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);           
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(set_alarm)

    /**
     * Cancels the alarm.
     * @param context
     */
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(cancel_alarm)
    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
        if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }

        // Disable {@code SampleBootReceiver} so that it doesn't automatically restart the 
        // alarm when the device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(cancel_alarm)
}
```

SampleBootReceiver.java

```
package com.example.android.scheduler;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * This BroadcastReceiver automatically (re)starts the alarm when the device is
 * rebooted. This receiver is set to be disabled (android:enabled="false") in the
 * application's manifest file. When the user sets the alarm, the receiver is enabled.
 * When the user cancels the alarm, the receiver is disabled, so that rebooting the
 * device will not trigger this receiver.
 */
// BEGIN_INCLUDE(autostart)
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    SampleAlarmReceiver alarm = new SampleAlarmReceiver();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.setAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
//END_INCLUDE(autostart)
```

SampleSchedulingService.java

```
package com.example.android.scheduler;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * This {@code IntentService} does the app's actual work.
 * {@code SampleAlarmReceiver} (a {@code WakefulBroadcastReceiver}) holds a
 * partial wake lock for this service while the service does its work. When the
 * service is finished, it calls {@code completeWakefulIntent()} to release the
 * wake lock.
 */
public class SampleSchedulingService extends IntentService {
    public SampleSchedulingService() {
        super("SchedulingService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "Scheduling Demo";
    // An ID used to post the notification.
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    // The string the app searches for in the Google home page content. If the app finds 
    // the string, it indicates the presence of a doodle.  
    public static final String SEARCH_STRING = "doodle";
    // The Google home page URL from which the app fetches content.
    // You can find a list of other Google domains with possible doodles here:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_domains
    public static final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(service_onhandle)
        // The URL from which to fetch content.
        String urlString = URL;

        String result ="";

        // Try to connect to the Google homepage and download content.
        try {
            result = loadFromNetwork(urlString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.connection_error));
        }

        // If the app finds the string "doodle" in the Google home page content, it
        // indicates the presence of a doodle. Post a "Doodle Alert" notification.
        if (result.indexOf(SEARCH_STRING) != -1) {
            sendNotification(getString(R.string.doodle_found));
            Log.i(TAG, "Found doodle!!");
        } else {
            sendNotification(getString(R.string.no_doodle));
            Log.i(TAG, "No doodle found. :-(");
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the BroadcastReceiver.
        SampleAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        // END_INCLUDE(service_onhandle)
    }

    // Post a notification indicating whether a doodle was found.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
               this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.doodle_alert))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

//
// The methods below this line fetch content from the specified URL and return the
// content as a string.
//
    /** Given a URL string, initiate a fetch operation. */
    private String loadFromNetwork(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        String str ="";

        try {
            stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
            str = readIt(stream);
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }      
        }
        return str;
    }

    /**
     * Given a string representation of a URL, sets up a connection and gets
     * an input stream.
     * @param urlString A string representation of a URL.
     * @return An InputStream retrieved from a successful HttpURLConnection.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Start the query
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        return stream;
    }

    /** 
     * Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
     * @param stream InputStream containing HTML from www.google.com.
     * @return String version of InputStream.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private String readIt(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) 
            builder.append(line);
        reader.close();
        return builder.toString();

    }
}
```

I had to add the android-support-v4.jar file to the build path first of all to make it work.

I am getting notifications after every 2 mins, but on clicking the "Cancel Alarm" button, the alarm is not getting canceled.

So , I tried removing the if condition in the cancelAlarm function, but I then got a java.nullpointerexception.

So basically, the alarmMgr is becoming null.

But, I am not able to understand why.

Also, since this is a sample code, I think there must be no errors in it, so I must be missing out on something.

Comment: Could someone please take a look, I have been stuck at this since quite a while..

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the instance of alarmManager (alarmMgr) could be uninitialized, as it is initialized in setAlarm. So you have to initialize it also in the cancelAlarm method, in case it is null.

SampleAlarmReceiver.java:

```
public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {        
    if (alarmMgr==null) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);           
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 , intent, 0);
    try{
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        Log.e("Alarma cancelada", action );
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error alarma", "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
    }
    .
    .
    .
```