# How to replace the deprecated WakefulBroadcastReceiver when scheduling alarms in a reminders app?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-jobscheduler

**Use case**: I'm working on a feature of the app that allows users to set up 
 weekly repeating reminders at different time/day which will create a notification upon execution. This reminders can't be missed, so the app should wake up the phone even if it's in DOZE mode. The code (based on the links I point below) is done years ago, everything works fine, but when targeting newer APIs I face the below issue.

**Issue:** WakefulBroadcastReceiver is **Deprecated**.

I tried to search here *"[android] AlarmManager jobscheduler WakefulBroadcastReceiver"* or in Google, but haven't found anything solving this question.

I see hundreds of posts discussing the question of using AlarmManager vs JobScheduler. 
But I struggle to find the ones with real alarm scheduling to implement a reminders app.

What I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992351/android-training-sample-scheduler-sample-unable-to-stop-alarm), [here](https://github.com/hnrainll/learn-android/blob/master/Scheduler/src/com/example/android/scheduler/SampleAlarmReceiver.java), [here](https://github.com/alphamu/PrayTime-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alimuzaffar/ramadanalarm/scheduler/SalaatAlarmReceiver.java) and [here](https://github.com/redapple1900/ClinicalTrialTracker/blob/master/src/com/yuanwei/android/AlarmReceiver.java) are very old examples solving this problem. But all rely on WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

I imagine that some alternative like JobScheduler needs to replace the WakefulBroadcastReceiver, but maybe there's no need for my use case.

When alarm is triggered, I do next:

- given the input params from the intent, search realm db for the model
- display a Notification
- set next alarm (will query db again)

Could I just do this?

```
PendingIntent.getService(context, 30, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Where Intent is a simple IntentService (actually the one that WakefulBroadcastReceiver was invoking) that does all the job in onHandleIntent.

Or I need to use some mechanism to hold the WAKE_LOCK?

**UPDATE 1**: I've just came across [this](http://chalup.github.io/blog/2014/02/20/when-do-you-absolutely-need/) post. Looks like there're chances that what's inside onHandleIntent won't have enough time to be executed. How to know the time I have?

**UPDATE 2**: I've Successfully paired AlarmManager with JobScheduler so that when user's alarm is fired, a job is scheduled to check the db in background and show a notification, but when targeting API 28, it gets banned and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a common use case and one I'm also struggling with. The only promising answer I've found is in the comment by ViciDroid at https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/71arjj/im_confused_about_android_o_and_task_execution/ 
Essentially ViciDroid suggests:
"Do the wake lock yourself and extend from a regular broadcast receiver. The Google docs have sample code for PowerManager. It's the same as how you would have to do this before the WakefulBroadcastReceiver was a thing.

Also register your broadcast explicitly due to the implicit broadcast ban."

I haven't tried it yet but it sounds promising - hopefully will try soon and report back.